# How to get brinary image url in odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo

I have to upload image in odoo via binary field and then get image url using compute method in odoo.

Below Code

```
image = fields.Binary(string='Category Image', required=True)
image_url = fields.Char('Image URL', compute="get_image_url")

def get_image_url(self):
    web_base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param( 'web.base.url' )
    for record in self:
        # record.image_url = f'{web_base_url}/web/image/{self._name}/{record.id}/{record.image}'
        record.image_url = f'{web_base_url}/web/image?model={self._name}&id={record.id}&field=image'
        print(record.image_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in the base module, where Odoo computes the [flag image URL](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_lang.py#L51-L60)

```
lang.flag_image_url = f"/web/image/res.lang/{lang.id}/flag_image"
```

You need to provide the model name, record ID, and the binary field name.

***Example:***

```
record.image_url = f'/web/image/{self._name}/{record.id}/image'
```

Comment: Problem is , Image showing in Firefox browser but not showing in chorome and other browsers

Comment: I tested it on the latest chrome version for Linux, and it is working.

Comment: i also want to get image into postman response, is that possible?